# Keep element data when extracting sessions

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Similarly to the [top wikipedia sessions example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/top_wikipedia_sessions.py) I have the following test data

```
EDITS = [
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 0, 'username': 'user1', 'action': 'a'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 1, 'username': 'user1', 'action': 'b'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 20, 'username': 'user1', 'action': 'a'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 132, 'username': 'user2', 'action': 'a'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 500, 'username': 'user2', 'action': 'b'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 3601, 'username': 'user2', 'action': 'b'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 3602, 'username': 'user2', 'action': 'a'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 8004, 'username': 'user2', 'action': 'a'}),
      json.dumps({'timestamp': 9320, 'username': 'user1', 'action': 'b'})
  ]
```

I would like to split the dataset into sessions per `username` and then for each **user session** count the user actions. So for the previous dataset and one hour max gap (3600 seconds), I want to get the following result:

```
EXPECTED = [
      'user1 : [0.0, 3620.0), a: 2, b: 1',
      'user2 : [132.0, 7202.0), a: 2, b: 2',
      'user2 : [8004.0, 11604.0), a: 1, b: 0',
      'user1 : [9320.0, 12920.0), a: 0, b: 1',
  ]
```

Contrary to the wikipedia sessions example I need to keep the complete element data and not only the key in order to use within my custom combiner function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a `CombineFn` that counts the number of actions of each type, using a dictionary of counts as the accumulator. Then, you can just use session windows in a collection keyed by user ID with that combiner.

See the Beam programming guide section on [Combine Fns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-combine) for ideas on how to write one.